# Programmatically updating quote items in Magento2

Tags: magento2.2, php-7, quoteitem

**I'm trying to update quote programmatically.**

**In controller file:**

```
 public function execute()
        {
    $id = 298;
   
    $params['id'] = 298;
    $params['product'] = 6765;
    $params['selected_configurable_option'] = '';
    $params['related_product'] = '';
    $params['form_key'] = 'S3Tlt9UviUqCPaIu';
    $params ['super_attribute'] = array('135' => '608');
     $params['qty'] = 3;


    if (!isset($params['options'])) {
        $params['options'] = [];
    }
    try {
        if (isset($params['qty'])) {
            $filter = new \Zend_Filter_LocalizedToNormalized(
                    ['locale' => $this->_objectManager->get(
                        \Magento\Framework\Locale\ResolverInterface::class
                )->getLocale()]
            );
            $params['qty'] = $filter->filter($params['qty']);
            
        }

        $quoteItem = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemById($id);
        if (!$quoteItem) {
            throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('We can\'t find the quote item.'));
        }

        $item = $this->cart->updateItem($id, new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($params));

        $this->cart->save();}
```

> **what can i do?**

Comment: Mano, did you get any solutions for this?

Comment: Hi Mano, any solutions u got for this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Plz try with below solutions and check any error throw or not.

```
$quoteItem = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemById($id);
            if (!$quoteItem) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('We can\'t find the quote item.'));
            }

            $item = $this->cart->updateItem($id, new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($params));
            if (is_string($item)) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__($item));
            }
            if ($item->getHasError()) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__($item->getMessage()));
            }
        $this->cart->save();
```

Comment: Already trying this code....I check the code flow using echo and exit;the code flow does not cross this line................................. $item = $this->cart->updateItem($id, new \Magento\Framework\DataObject($params));

Comment: anything mention after this line ....... not working

Comment: Its throw Uncaught Exception: Serialization of 'Closure' is not allowed in magento/framework/Session/SessionManager.php

Answer (score 0):

> **Try this code**

```
<?php

namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Controller\Index;

use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\ResultFactory;

class Editcart extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $request;
    protected $cart;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $Request

    ) {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        $this->request = $request;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultFactory->create(ResultFactory::TYPE_REDIRECT);
        // get cart product data
        $data = $this->request->getParams();
        ///$data['quoteid'] is current qoute item id
        // $data['prdid'] is product id
        if (!isset($data['quoteid'])) {
            $this->messageManager->addError(__('Invalid product data.'));
            $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
            return $resultRedirect;
        }
        // get quote product by items id
        try {
            $quote_data = $this->cart->getQuote()->getItemById($data['quoteid']);

            if (!$quote_data) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__('We can\'t find the quote item.'));
            }

            $quote_params = $quote_data->getBuyRequest();

            // update product data
            if (isset($data['super_attribute'])) {
                $quote_params->setSuperAttribute($data['super_attribute'][$data['prdid']]);
            } elseif (isset($data['links'])) {
                $quote_params->setLinks($data['links']);
            } elseif ((isset($data['bundle_option'])) && (isset($data['bundle_option_qty']))) {
                $quote_params->setBundleOption($data['bundle_option']);
                $quote_params->setBundleOptionQty($data['bundle_option_qty']);
            } else {
                $quote_params = $quote_data->getBuyRequest();
            }

            //update custom options
            if (isset($data['options'])) {
                $quote_params->setOptions($data['options']);
            }

            // update qty
            $quote_params->setQty($data['prdqty']);

            // update product data with qty
            $item = $this->cart->getQuote()->updateItem($data['quoteid'], $quote_params);

            if (is_string($item)) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__($item));
            }
            if ($item->getHasError()) {
                throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(__($item->getMessage()));
            }
            // save cart item
            $this->cart->save();
            $this->messageManager->addSuccessMessage(__('Product has been successfully updated.'));
        } catch (\Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addNoticeMessage($e->getMessage());
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            $this->messageManager->addExceptionMessage($e, __('We can\'t update the item right now.'));
        }
        $resultRedirect->setUrl($this->_redirect->getRefererUrl());
        return $resultRedirect;
    }
}
```

***I Hope This Helps You.***